# Drupal 7 multi-site, multiple database and 1 shared code base

Tags: database, drupal-7, shared-data

I want to develop drupal multi-site with this structure:

- One shared codebase drupal 7 multi-site, each web site has own database.
- One master web site that has some tables shared.
- Each multi site instances read some tables from master's database, not own database. For example conntent types, fields, views, rules and related configirations read only master's database. So I can develop all sites on one place.

As a result each site must use same content types, views, rules but different contents. I am user 1 of all sites. Sub site editors has create content and user permisions only. I dont want to share users accross sites. So I cant use domain acceess. Is it possible that?

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Drupal, belongs to http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module should allow you to accomplish what you are looking for:

https://drupal.org/project/domain

As it states in the module description you can share tables with the domain prefix module. You can select which tables will be shared and which ones will not.

Comment: Note that the domain module supports subdomains, but not multiple domains (though I suppose you could probably overcome that with a reverse proxy or something) :(